# Duotone plots with cyan and black

Tags: plotting, color

What's the typical way to make Mathematica plots use purely cyan and black? Maybe there's a fairly standard method, since publishers often require this?

It also seems like some plot types take `PlotStyle` argument while others (for example, `ContourPlot3D`) take `ColorFunction`, so maybe the method differs depending on the plot type?

Comment: You can use a color function like `Blend[{Black, Cyan}, t]` for plots. For images, you can use that with `Colorize[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use

```
Blend[{Black,Cyan}, <appropriate fraction>]
```

Two examples:

```
DensityPlot[
 Sin[x] Sin[y],
 {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Black, Cyan}, #] &)
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[
 {Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x]},
 {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 PlotStyle -> {
   Blend[{Black, Cyan}, 0],
   Blend[{Black, Cyan}, 0.5],
   Blend[{Black, Cyan}, 1]
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]